# python 3.6 json.dumps ValueError using allow_nan=True

Tags: python, json

I am currently working on moving from python 2.7 to python 3.6

Python 2.7 code that works

```
json.dump(data, ignore_nan=True)
```

Python 3.6 code

```
json.dumps(charts, allow_nan=False)
```

Error Message:

```
{ValueError}Out of range float values are not JSON complaint
```

**How should I dump the information ignoring nan values?**

Example:

```
 "series": [
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": 60.6,
                            "x": 1538431200000.0
                        },
                        {
                            "value": 80.6,
                            "x": 1538434800000.0
                        },
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga I did and post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things the one that work as:

```
import simplejson
simplejson.dumps(data, ignore_nan=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`allow_nan=True` should do the trick. I didn't have any problems with the option allow_nan.

```
>>> a = [{"k": 1, "v": float('nan')}, {"k": 2, "v": float('inf')}]
>>> a
[{'k': 1, 'v': nan}, {'k': 2, 'v': inf}]
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(a)
'[{"k": 1, "v": NaN}, {"k": 2, "v": Infinity}]'
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.version)
3.6.6 (default, Jul 19 2018, 14:25:17) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5)]
```